# TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, builtin_function_or_method found

Tags: python, string

I am trying to write some code that is given a string and reverses it, while capitalizing the first letter of the reversed string. for some, reason i get this message when running

**Code:**

[image: 1]

**Error:**

[image: 1]

Comment: Hi and welcom to StackOverflow. Please provide copy-pastable code and please don't use links for error messages but paste them here in the correct formatting.

Comment: please are your code.

Comment: Are you trying to do this ``"abc"[-1::-1].capitalize()``

Answer (score 1):

In your `capitalize()` function you are calling `upper()` method without parenthesis. It returning the function object instead of string that's causing the problem.

Change this to

```
stringA[i] = stringA[i].upper
```

this

```
stringA[i] = stringA[i].upper()
```

Simple solution to your question using [str.capitalize()](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=capitalize#str.capitalize)

```
res = string[::-1].capitalize()
```

Answer (score 0):

There's just one simple problem in your code. you forgot to put the `()` after the `upper` method.

here's how you can write the code:

```
def capitalize(stringA):
    notAplha = [" ",".",",","/","?","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","0"]
    for i in range(1):
        if stringA[i] in notAplha:
            continue
        else:
            stringA[i]=stringA[i].upper()
        return stringA
def reverseit(string):
    string = list(string)
    string.reverse()
    string = capitalize(string)
    string = "".join(string)
    return string
print(reverseit(str(input())))
```

there seems to be an issue with you code. it does't work properly if i insert a number at the end for input

So, try this `capitalize(stringA[i+1:-1])` in the if condition. It'll look like this:

```
def capitalize(stringA):
    notAplha = [" ",".",",","/","?","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","0"]
    for i in range(len(stringA)):
        if stringA[i] in notAplha:
            capitalize(stringA[i+1:-1])
            continue
        else:
            stringA[i]=stringA[i].upper()
        return stringA
def reverseit(string):
    string = list(string)
    string.reverse()
    string = capitalize(string)
    string = "".join(string)
    return string
print(reverseit("dsaddsa00000"))
```

output will be:

```
00000Asddasd
```